# How to legend Plot Groups of Stacked Bars in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, bar-chart, legend

I have some data I want to draw in bars.

Let says I have a group of 3 values for two conditions and a group of 2 values for the same conditions

```
y3 = [ 1, 1, 1; 0, 1, 2];
y2 = [1 , 1 ; 0, 2];
```

I know how to use `plotBarStackGroups` (https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32884-plot-groups-of-stacked-bars) to build the bars.

The code to build the bars (maybe it's not the best way)

```
B = floor(rand(2,2,3));
B(1,:,:) = [[y2(1,:),0] ; y3(1,:)];
B(2,:,:) = [[y2(2,:),0] ; y3(2,:)];
label = {'condition 1', 'condition 2'};
plotBarStackGroups(B,label);
```

But I want to obtain something like this [image: bar plot I want to have]

and I see two problems : legend by groups (or not prevent the colors to be shared) and the fact that the groups don't have the same length.
I could do two different figures but if I can regroup them, I think it's better

Comment: I don't understand the first part of your question (you want each group to have its own combination of colors, or want different colors inside a group?), for the second part: to make groups of same length pad the smaller with NaN's.

Comment: @Gryphon NaN's ? Ok
I don't understand the difference between "each group having its own combination" and "different colors inside a group"

Comment: @Cclie in the picture above each group (left and right bars each month) has it own combination on colors, but the combinations are the same for every month. Do you want this or opposite: each moth has unique combination while two bars per month have the same?

Comment: @Gryphon The first one bacause every month you show the same thing.

Comment: could you please provide (part of) the data you want to be plotted?

Comment: @Gryphon I don't have them right now (holidays) but you can use y3 and y2 I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly got your question

```
vals = {rand(3,3) rand(4,3)}; %sample data
max_len = max(cellfun(@(x) size(x,1), vals));
pad_vals = cellfun(@(x) cat(1,x,nan(max_len-size(x,1),size(x,2))), vals, 'un',0);
pad_vals = cat(3,pad_vals{:});
figure, 
subplot(1,2,1), bar(vals{1},'stacked'), set(gca,'Ylim',[0 3]), 
subplot(1,2,2),bar(vals{2},'stacked'), set(gca,'Ylim',[0 3])
%I slightly modified plotBarStackGroups to output bar handles
h=plotBarStackGroups(permute(pad_vals,[1 3 2]),{'1','2','3','4'}) %reorder the matrix according to the function needs
cgroup={'r','m','y';'k','b','c'};
cgroup=cgroup'; h=h'; % For comfortable iteration
for k=1:numel(h),
    set(h(k),'Facecolor',cgroup{k}),
end
legend({'1','2','3','4','5','6'})
```

[image: Plot data sets separately]
[image: Plot data sets together]

Comment: It is equivalent to `cellfun(@(x) {somefun(x)}, cell_array)` or `cellfun(@(x) somefun(x), cell_array, 'UniformOutput',false) `- indication that cellfun outputs a cell array of same size as input one. The author of cellfun is as lazy as me, he checked only for two first characters of optional argument

Comment: @Gryphon when I try to execute command "h=plotBarStackGroups(permute(pad_vals,[1 3 2]),{'1','2','3','4'}) " Matlab gives me error "Error using plotBarStackGroups Too many output arguments." It is worth to note that I'm using Matlab 2013b. Do you have any suggestion for solving the problem?
thanks in advance

Comment: @Mahmoud, by default plotBarStackGroups has no output. You should edit the function to output local variable h - the handles of bars.